# I need to automatically inject div class to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to find a Function filter that automatically injects `div class` to `Iframe` in older word-press posts. Right now I use following code for current posts :

```
<div class="playplay"> <iframe src="some-content"> </iframe> </div>
```

And now I want to apply these changes to all past posts with one automatic code.

Please assist,

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with a iFrame whose display a wordpress blog, normally you can't modify DOM into iframe if these domains are differents.

Solution : use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

On your website, when iframe is loaded send a message to wordpress, when wordpress will receive the message put your div where you want.
I used that to change Height's iframe automatically.

If you want help ask me, I don't know if it's really good for your issue
 but I hope ;)

Comment: I use wordpress.org.

Answer (score 0):

I sue this code in my website just to make the area to look bit more darker.
Here is my css code.

```
.playplay {filter:alpha(opacity=70);opacity:.7;padding:0 0 0px 0;overflow:hidden}grey,.grey,a.grey,a.grey{color:#9c9c9c!important;}
```

I hope someone to help me out.